# Add view with contextual filter to XML sitemap

Tags: xml-sitemap

I setup a view with the following path www.example.com/profile/% (the user contextual filter i added is the username of the). These displays the profile of each user.

Please is there a way to add the view to the XML sitemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an XML Sitemap Custom submodule in the XML Sitemap module

You can use this to set Page Views' paths for inclusion in the XML Sitemap

You might also check this module out: https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap_aliases
From the project page:
"Anything with a path in the aliases table can now be included in your XMLsitemap by the click of a button! (This is particularly useful when you have too many to enter manually as custom links, for example: views with arguments!)"